# Looping through wagtail contents

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I’m using wagtail to manage content in my Django app. In my model, I used a structured block like so:

```
# prefered 
class SectionBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    header = blocks.CharBlock()
    content = blocks.RichTextBlock()
```

My page is expected to have multiple distinct headers like introduction, conclusion, etc however the template iteration keeps looping through the first header (introduction). The question is do I rename each item in my `SectionBlock` class so I can directly access it in the template or there is a simpler solution?

```
class SectionBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    header1 = blocks.CharBlock()
    content1 = blocks.RichTextBlock()
    header2 = blocks.CharBlock()
    content2 = blocks.RichTextBlock()
```

```
{% for block in blocks %}
{{ block.value.header1 }}
{{ block.value.header2 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Are the section blocks added / removed by the editor or is there a fixed template that the editors must follow?

Comment: Yes, sections are added by editors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom SectionBlock can be used with a StreamField, allowing the editors to add as many sections as needed.

**models.py**

```
class SectionBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    header = blocks.CharBlock()
    content = blocks.RichTextBlock()


class ExamplePage(Page):
    body = StreamField(
        [
            ('section', SectionBlock())
        ], blank=True
    )
```

**template.html**

```
{% for section in page.body %}
   {{ section.value.header }}
   {{ section.value.content }}
{% endfor %}
```